# Why are parameters passed via RDI, R10, R11 and not via stack?

Tags: c#, assembly, x86-64, masm, calling-convention

So, I am writing a simple program that generates a mandelbrot set, which lets you decide to use either function written in C++ or in assemlby to generate the set. Main program is written in C#. I am using Windows 10 with VS2022, x64 and AMD processor.

I am passing 7 parameters (one byte* and six ints) to the assembly procedure and was trying to access them. The first 4 were as expected passed via RCX, RDX, R8 and R9 registers but I wasn't able to access remaining 3 parameters. At [RSP+40] was some random data. Then I tried using stack frame approach (as I had declared 2 locals) but still the values looked random. I finally noticed that my missing 5th, 6th and 7th parameters are passed via RDI, R10 and R11. Is there any calling convention where it is done like that, or am I just missing something?

On a side note about half a year ago when I was experimenting with parameter passing in assembly they were passed as expected, meaning: RCX, RDX, R8, R9 and then onto stack.

Here's declaration of my assembly function:

```
[DllImport(masmDllPath)]
private static extern void generateMandelMASM(
    byte[] bmp, int rowCount, int rowNum, int resX, int resY, int alignment, int iterCount);
```

I am calling mentioned function in C# via delegate in separate thread using lambda expresion, like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i < settings.threadCount; i++)
{
    int localIter = i; // Necessary because lambda captures by reference, not value

    threads[i] = new Thread(() => generateMandel(bitmapRows[localIter], rowsPerThread[localIter],
        rowOffset[localIter], settings.resX, settings.resY, alignment, settings.iterationCount));
}
```

Part of the assembly procedure:

```
.code

generateMandelMASM PROC

    LOCAL alignment: DWORD
    LOCAL rowCount: QWORD
    
    ;--------- Prologue ---------
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    sub rbp, 16     ; subtracting number of locals * 8 bytes
    
    mov r11d, dword ptr [rbp+50o]
    mov alignment, r10d
```

Explicitly stating calling convention in DllImport doesn't change how the parameters are passed.

Comment: if you don't need to interact with external compiled code then you can use any customized calling convention you want

Comment: 40 is the wrong offset, it would have been right if you didn't `push rbp`

Comment: You're right, but under [rsp+48] was also random value

Comment: What code did you write to find that out though? The code that you showed is pretty odd. `sub rbp, 16` is pretty much wrong (to allocate stack space you need to subtract from `rsp`, not `rbp`), and `[rbp+50o]` (odd to use octal but OK) takes neither the `push rbp` into account nor the `sub rbp, 16`

Comment: Also it seems that if you use `LOCAL` MASM automatically sets up a stack frame, or so people say. That would wreak havoc here. I never use that feature..

Comment: The code in the caller that stores function args to the stack usually has the values in registers first.  It's not rare that some of the non-arg-passing registers will happen to hold interesting values when the `call` executes, but that's just an implementation detail that happens to be true for this specific call site.  Use a debugger to examine stack memory and verify that the args are where they're supposed to be, and to debug your broken code to access the right places in the stack frame.

Comment: BTW, the first 4 args are in RCX, RDX, R8, R9 in the Windows x64 calling convention, not R9, R10.  One of your paragraphs got this mixed up.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes it should be R8, R9, my bad

Comment: You can [edit] to remove that distraction / confusion for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

The fifth parameter is at [rsp+0x20] before the function call. After the call instruction pushes rip and the function prologue pushes rbp, the fifth parameter is at [rbp+0x30].

Comment: Why would pushing a 64-bit register move the stack pointer by 128 bits (0x10 bytes)?

Comment: Right, because the x86_64 architecture doesn't have a LR to hold the return address.  Answer would be clearer if you included that 0x28 intermediate condition.

Comment: Normally you wouldn't change rbp after setting it to rsp. (I'm sure that `sub rbp, 16` is a typo and it should be changing rsp.) Nevertheless, after `sub rbp, 16`, the fifth parameter is at [rbp+0x40] or [rbp+100o].

Answer (score -1):

The x64 calling convention uses registers first before using the stack, since registers are much faster (and don't have to be later moved into registers, since they already are in registers). You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/x64-calling-convention?view=msvc-170):

[image]

Comment: The OP knows the first 4 are passed in registers.  They're incorrectly assuming that later args aren't on the stack because their buggy code isn't loading them, and they've noticed that this caller happens to leave copies of them in a few random registers.  Your answer doesn't do much to correct that, in fact it sounds like you're agreeing with them about passing in RDI, R10, and R11 unless you look at the details of the table image.  They seem to think C# is using a custom calling convention, so linking the standard one doesn't correct that either.

Comment: What? How is linking the official calling convention for x64 not directly and conclusively answer him that that is indeed how it works, there's no mistake going on here? Also what does "look at the details of the table image" even mean? Why would I post that if I didn't look at the details?